# What are these aircraft at AMARG? Why are they dismantled this way?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, aircraft-maintenance

At the AMARG boneyard (Tucson desert, Arizona), there are tons of aircraft, but a limited number of models are dismantled according a special way: wings or tail or both separated from the fuselage:

[image: AMARG boneyard, START dismantled aircraft]
<sup>Image from [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@32.1503359,-110.8237789,518m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en)</sup>

[image: AMARG boneyard, START dismantled aircraft]
<sup>[Source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/leezpics/39324818072), reframed</sup>

I doubt all tails will suddenly be used as spare parts...

What are those military aircraft? why are they systematically dismantled this way?

(Not sure the question is on topic.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some B-52s and other aircraft were put out of commission as part of the [START treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/START_I).  They were [dismantled in such a way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/START_I#Implementation) that the Russians could verify this with satellite reconnaissance, just as in the photo above.

Comment: So apparently the B-52s were sold for scrap, but for some reason are still at AMARG after the 3-month period of satellite observation. Does that means that other aircraft are not in the scope of the START treaties?

Comment: @mins I've no idea. The Google image could be old - perhaps more recent imagery has been classified? The B52s were classed as "nuclear delivery systems" if the tail was still on - even though they were in the boneyard. Whether they are still there or not, who knows?

Answer (score 7):

Article linked in the source below mentions the *Strategic Arms Reduction Treaty*, as Simon [said](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29604/14897).

[image]

> The 39th and final B-52G Stratofortress, tail number 58-0224, accountable under the New START Treaty (Strategic Arms Reduction Treaty) with Russia, sits among the planes.

Source: [dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3092724/Aircraft-graveyard-holds-hidden-gems-tell-story-American-Air-Force-armed-teeth-fight-Communism.html)

Comment: Thank you ymb1. This is a great link, very interesting. Btw, the photos turn abstract figures into concrete things. How much money is ending in this graveyard...

Comment: @mins - snarky comment warning....."enough to make sure WW3 never happened!" I used to live there, it was fun to watch when they shredded one of them into ribbons.